# LABVIEW: Logging every nth element from unsigned long integer

Tags: sample, labview, waveform

I am curently working on modifying an existing programm. It currently gets a signal and loggs the data to a tdms file. Since the files are way too big for further evaluation, I am now trying to implement a threshhold that decides whether all the incoming data needs to be logged or just every nth element (so only the interesting parts are high resolution and thus the files are smaller and easier to handle).

I am pretty new to labview and have tried a few things, but i could get it to work. The existing Programm saves a 1d-Array of waveform to a tdms file and my idea is to take those two cases and put the condition "true" or "false" from the threshhold (which still needs to be implemented as well). If above the threshhold just leave everything as it is and if below then only let every nth point pass to the logging.

So how do I only use every nth point of a 1d-Array of waveform? Am I thinking too complicated? Or is my idea basicly right and I just cant get it to work?

Thanks a lot already. The picture shows the logging process of the existing programm.

[Logging Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY37v.png)

P.S.: If my problem didnt get clear, please ask further questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions from Array pallette to build your own decimation mechanism that would allow you to select dynamically how many elements to skip.
Example attached:
[image: decimate 1D array example]

[image]